# Any sequence in a compact metric space has an accumulation point but not necesseraly a limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

Would it be correct to claim that $\forall X$ compact metric space and $\forall \{x_n\} \subset X$ sequence in it, $\{x_n\}$ has an accumulation point in $X$, but not necessarily a limit in it?

Comment: That's right. Clearly not every sequence converges, but every sequence in a compact space has an accumulation point (also called cluster point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True. A metric space is compact $\iff$ it's sequentially compact, that's if every sequence in the space has a convergent subsequence, that's if every sequence has an accumulation point (but not necessarily a limit).

Answer (score 0):

Correct, since every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.  For example, $\{(-1)^n,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \}$ has 2 accumulation points in [-2,2], but no limit point.  If there is only one accumulation point, that point is also a limit point.

Comment: "Correct, since every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence." the OP is not limited to bounded sequences.